# Inconveniente con la estructura while en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo, agradezco por favor la colaboración que me puedan suministrar con el siguiente código en lenguaje  R, dentro del editor RStudio:

```
install.packages("svDialogs") # Para instalar el paquete
library(svDialogs) 
i <- 1
cont <- 0
while(i <= 10 && cont <= 10){
  x <- dlgInput(message="Digite valor: ")$res
  
  
  if (x %% 2 == 0) {
    print(x)
    cat(x)
    i <- i + 1
    cont <- cont + 1
    
    
    
  } else if (x %% 2 != 0){
    i <- i + 1
    cont <- cont + 1
    
  }
}
```

Al ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error: unexpected '{' in "While(i <= 10 & cont <= 10){"
```

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: El código que muestras no da el error que indicas, el único problema es con  `x %% 2 == 0` por que `x`  es un `character`, pero lo solucionas así: `x <- as.numeric(dlgInput(message="Digite valor: ")$res)`

Comment: Y por otro lado,  bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Ahora me doy cuenta, el error es tipográfico, has escrito `While()` en vez de `while()`, me doy cuenta por el mensaje de error, por que en el ejemplo lo has corregido